# Laravel PHP: Get values out of Recursion Function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `invoice_schedule_table` which is structured like:
id, previous_invoice_schedule_id, due_date 
7559, , 01-06-2021
7772, 7559, 15-06-2021
7773, 7772, 20-06-2021

I am trying to create a looping/recursive function which will ultimately give me back the last due_date (20-06-2021) if I am opening up any invoice schedule(ID: 7559, 7772) from the UI.

```
function latestRescheduledInvoiceSchedule($invoiceScheduleId) {

    $rescheduledPaymentSchedule = InvoiceSchedule::where('previous_invoice_schedule_id', $invoiceScheduleId)->first();

    if(isset($rescheduledPaymentSchedule)) {
        latestRescheduledInvoiceSchedule($rescheduledPaymentSchedule->id);
    }
}
```

But I am unable to figure out how to get the value once it reaches the last record.

Any help regarding this?

Comment: Can't you just `break` once you reach a record where `previous_invoice_schedule_id` is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of recursive function. You can just use a loop of your choice to get the latest row like below:

```
<?php


function latestRescheduledInvoiceSchedule($invoiceScheduleId) {
    $payment_schedule_row = '';
    $rescheduledPaymentSchedule = '';
    do{
        $invoiceScheduleId = $rescheduledPaymentSchedule->id ?? $invoiceScheduleId;
        $payment_schedule_row = $rescheduledPaymentSchedule ?? '';
        $rescheduledPaymentSchedule = InvoiceSchedule::where('previous_invoice_schedule_id', $invoiceScheduleId)->first();
    }while(!empty($rescheduledPaymentSchedule));

    
    if(empty($payment_schedule_row)){
        $payment_schedule_row = InvoiceSchedule::find($invoiceScheduleId);
    }
    // rest of the code goes here
    dd($payment_schedule_row);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. Infact, did not get my head around that this can be achieved through a while loop.

Comment: @DebarunPal Great. I would still suggest you to look into https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html to reduce roundtrips to DB server with `with recursive cte` approach.

Answer (score 2):

You should retrieve the `due_date` value when the `$rescheduledPaymentSchedule` is not set, in this case it will be with an id of 7773:

```
function latestRescheduledInvoiceSchedule($invoiceScheduleId) {
    $rescheduledPaymentSchedule = InvoiceSchedule::where('previous_invoice_schedule_id', $invoiceScheduleId)->first();

    if($rescheduledPaymentSchedule) {
        latestRescheduledInvoiceSchedule($rescheduledPaymentSchedule->id);
    } else {
        // There is no further values, retrieve the `due_date` of the current invoiceScheduleId
        $last_record = InvoiceSchedule::find($invoiceScheduleId);
        if ($last_record) {
            $last_due_date = $last_record->due_date;
        }
    }
}
```